# How do I create flexible placeholder expressions (%d %s %d) in c?

Tags: c

The program lets you type in a math question such as:

```
Bob has 1 apple and Mike 2. What is the sum?
```

The program then understands the word "sum" and adds the two numbers together. At least that is what im trying to achieve. It doesnt work as im getting very large numbers. I suspect that the expression %d %s %d is not flexible enough and only works if the question is:

```
1 sum 2
```

The order seems to matter. So how do I make it flexible so that the order does not matter?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char question[100];
   char buffer[100];
   int result;
   int n1, n2;
   int operation;

   printf ("Your mathematical question: ");

   fgets(question, sizeof(question), stdin);
   fflush(stdin);

   if(strstr(question, "sum") || strstr(question, "add")){
        operation = 0;
   }

   sscanf(question, "%d %s %d", &n1, buffer, &n2);

   printf ("%d %d \n", n1, n2);

    switch(operation) {
        case 0: result = n1 + n2;
        break;
    }

   printf ("%d", result);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes *undefined behavior*. Do not use it.

Comment: Not sure that `sscanf` is the way to go here.

Comment: @MikeCAT im currently in school. The teacher told me to use it. Feel free to show me an alternative : (

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is still UB, even if your teacher tells yo to use it.

Comment: If you're after this kind of context inference you're not going to be able to parse generic patterns like this. Read some material about Natural Language Processing, there are some clever techniques out there.

Comment: You should tell your teacher to take some classes in C programming...

Comment: @Asperger What exactly is the reason to use it?

Comment: @Asperger: A standard compliant way to ensure the stdin buffer is empty would be an empty while loop: `while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` This reads characters from the buffer until EOL or EOF is encountered

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Wouldn't it block when no character is entered? One will have to explicitly send ^D or EOL..

Comment: What does the program do with `and`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, OP shouldn't attempt to clear stdin unless there are unwanted characters in there, of course (`ioctl` can tell you that). The real answer is that there is no simple, portable replacement for `fflush(stdin)`. If you're only targeting gcc, then the behaviour of `fflush(stdin)` is defined (implementation specific, non-standard, but documented and defined). Either way, there's tons of questions about flushing stdin on SO and other sites for the OP to sift through. Most of them will mention the while loop I've posted, along with the caveats

Answer (score 2):

Try using `strtok` to split your input string into a list of operators and operands.  The problem is that natural languages such as English do not have a formal order for operators and operands when expressing mathematical phrases, whereas you program requires this.

Splitting the input into operators and operands allows you to match them up in the order required.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum
{
    NO_OP,
    ADDITION,
    /* Add new operators here. */
}   operator_t;

/* One operator plus two operands. */
#define NUMBER_OF_ITEMS 3

int main()
{
    char question[100];
    char buffer[100];
    char *token;

    int result = 0;
    /* Extend this to allow more complex sentences with multiple operations. */
    int operands[2];
    int* nextOperand = &operands[0];
    int itemCount = 0;
    /* Turn this into an array to extend the parser. */
    operator_t operator = NO_OP;

    printf ("Your mathematical question: \r\n");

    fgets(question, sizeof(question), stdin);

    /* Tokens are seperated by SPACES in this example. */
    const char delims[] = " ";

    /* Get the first token. */
    token = strtok(question, delims);

    /* Walk through all tokens in the question string. */
    while((token != NULL)&&(NUMBER_OF_ITEMS > itemCount)) 
    {
        /* use strcmp to avoid matches on words like 'summertime'. */
        if((0 == strcmp(token, "sum")) || (0 == strcmp(token, "add")))
        {
            operator = ADDITION;
            itemCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Check that one integer can be parsed from the token. */
            if(1 == sscanf(token, "%d", nextOperand))
            {
                nextOperand++;
                itemCount++;
            }
        }

        /* Find the next token. */
        token = strtok(NULL, delims);
    }

    /* Perform the operation, if possible. */
    if((NUMBER_OF_ITEMS == itemCount) && (NO_OP != operator))
    {
        switch(operator)
        {
            case ADDITION:
                result = operands[0] + operands[1];
                printf("The answer to your question (%d + %d) is %d.\r\n",
                    operands[0], operands[1], result);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Oops, please ask my programmer to do some debugging.");
                break;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        printf ("I did not understand your question.\r\n");    
    }
}
```

Note that you will need to add much more error checking for decent robustness, but the code above should help illustrate how teh problem can be solved.

You can then use something like [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) to extend the functionality of your parser.

Comment: there seems to be an error on this line  token = strtok(NULL, s);

Comment: @Asperger  Yup, just spotted that.  Thank you.

Comment: What do you think of unwinds "regex style" solution? What is the disadvantage of both?

Comment: I still somehow get large numbers instead

Comment: @Asperger I've never used regex's for anything other than the most simple tasks, when the format of the input is known in advance.  It's not very extensible, even if you're prepared to build the regex dynamically.  It's really not the best way to learn about parsing.  It may work in this instance, but (IMO) is not the best approach, even if a regex library is available in C.

Comment: @Asperger Put in a few debug lines to `printf` each token and what they parse as (the operator_t value, the `sscanf` integer value, etc.).

Comment: @Asperger ...and I've just fixed another bug on the `prinf` output line (I forgot to add teh parameters).

Comment: NIcely done!   Suggest adding `'\n'` to the delimiter list so `"1 2 sum\n"` works.

Comment: Wow nice. Im a starter in C so this is really helpful.

Comment: #define NUMBER_OF_ITEMS 3 is not a library. How does that work? Sorry if I ask so much : (   The solutions works though

Comment: @Asperger `#define` is a C preprocessor directive that causes the text `NUMBER_OF_ITEMS` to be replaced by the value `3` wherever it occurs in your source code.  This means that you can change the value in one place, without having to manually go through your code and find it.  It also associates a handy, human-readable description of what the value is in place of a relatively meaningless number.  i.e. what does `if(itemCount==3)` really mean and why 3?

Comment: @Asperger You could replace that line with `static const int NUMBER_OF_ITEMS = 3;` and it would work the same (in this instance).  However, they are not the same thing at all.  It's like a constant, except that it only exists for the benefit of the programmer and the compiler.  There will be no entity (pointer, variable, constant, etc.) in the compiled software.  There are lots of resources on this site and the web in general relating to the C preprocessor - have a read around.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `"%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d"` might work, but this is rather iffy use of `sscanf()`.

The format specifier basically means "skip until you see a digit, convert one decimal number, then skip until the next digit and finally convert another decimal number". This of course assumes that the input doesn't start with the first number, and so on.

You should check the return value of `sscanf()` before relying on the variables having values.

Comment: I can use regular expressions in c? I never knew

Comment: @Asperger The code I showed is not a regular expression, it's a perfectly standard format specifier for `sscanf()` using the `%[]` and `%d` conversion specifiers.

Comment: A more detailed meaning: "find at least 1 non-digit, skip until you see a digit, convert one decimal number ..."  So `"1 sum 2"` fails.